# Filter from 2 list and get matching records using java8

Tags: java, java-8

I have two lists one is `messagePermissionResponseDTOList` and another `dispatchSMSQList`.
    I want to take out list of blocked numbers from `dispatchSMSQList`. Below is my working code snippet.
    Can you please guide how this can be converted Lambda expression or its correct.?
Working link with test data is https://repl.it/repls/FriendlyImmenseClasses

```
        TreeSet<Long> blockedNumbersSet = new TreeSet<>();
        for (MessagePermissionResponseDTO permission: messagePermissionResponseDTOList) {
            if (permission.isBlocked()) {
                blockedNumbersSet.add(permission.getPhoneNumber());
            }
        }
        List<DispatchSMSQ> blockedNumbers = dispatchSMSQList.stream().filter(t -> blockedNumbersSet.contains(t.getMdn())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.print("blockedNumbers-->"+ blockedNumbers.size());
```

Comment: Just use filter and collect to `Set` as you did in the lower part? Or do you want to combine both into one lambda?

Comment: Yes I was thinking to combine both into one lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
List<DispatchSMSQ> blockedNumbers = messagePermissionResponseDTOList.stream()
    .filter(MessagePermissionResponseDTO::isBlocked)
    .map(MessagePermissionResponseDTO::getPhoneNumber)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), 
        s -> dispatchSMSQList.stream()
            .filter(d -> s.contains(d.getMdn())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
 messagePermissionResponseDTOList
      .stream()
      .filter(MessagePermissionResponseDTO::isBlocked)
      .map(MessagePermissionResponseDTO::getPhoneNumber)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: Thank you. It solves partially. Can we do second part as well to get blocked numbers from dispatchSMSQList at once or its correct to filter first blocked numbers and filter out those from dispatchSMSQList?